# Date Picker reopens in wrong Edittext

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext

I've got several EditTexts in one of my Android app activities. The one for picking a date works perfectly fine, the date picker dialog shows up, you choose a date, the date is then set in that EditText, no problem.

The problem is that when I *later* open another EditText, one in which you're just suppose to provide some text (the one called 'leggtil'), the Date Picker Dialog shows up again! Anyone know what's wrong? I'll show all relevant code here:

```
private DatePickerDialog velgdato;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
private EditText dato;
private Calendar mycalendar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lag_liste);

    dato = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.laglistedato);    
    final EditText leggtil = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.laglisteadditem);

    mycalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mycalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            mycalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            mycalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            oppdater();
        }
    };

    dato.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            new DatePickerDialog(LagListe.this, date, mycalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mycalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mycalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });

    leggtil.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (leggtil.getText().toString() != null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), leggtil.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
            }

            else
                return false;
        }
    });
    }

    private void oppdater() {
    String format = "MM/dd/yy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);

    dato.setText(sdf.format(mycalendar.getTime()));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you set the onFocusChangeListener, which is called every time the Views focus changes (both to in-focus and out-of-focus). Try this:

```
dato.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            new DatePickerDialog(LagListe.this, date, mycalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mycalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mycalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On second EditText click Date Picker is showing due to `setOnFocusChangeListener` method is called when focus is remove from first EditText.

Add if condition inside `onFocusChange` and show Date Picker only when focus is on First EditText like change `onFocusChange` method as  :

```
@Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(v.getId()==R.id.laglistedato){
            new DatePickerDialog(LagListe.this, date,
                               mycalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                               mycalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                    mycalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }else{
              // do nothing...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks guys, that fixed the problem. :)

I now got a new problem with the 'leggtil' EditText though, maybe I should post it as another question, but if you know right off the bat, please help. ^^ It's acting really strange, the toast shows up if I click backspace, and the toast never leaves the screen, etc? The toast is just a test before I'll do something else with the text entirely, but still, I need to know there's not a problem there.

Comment: @OhDannyBoy: `onKey ` method execute every time when user press any key on keyboard. that's why Toast message is always showing. when u want to show Toast Message?

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.. Duh, I should have known that, lol. Anyway, I want the toast to show when the user is finishing typing his stuff and then clicks the enter icon. Should I use 'onClickListener' instead, or what?

Comment: @OhDannyBoy: try to use `if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) { //your toast message}`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. :)